# Execute method after multiple async setStates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, setstate

Wait wait. Before you mark it as duplicate, just read it once, its not.
So i am working on a react project. There i have around 10 different methods and in each of those methods it has both synchronous and asynchronous calls (majority of async calls are React's setState methods).

I have want to place kinda of a loader before the execution of those 10 methods and remove it after every synchronous and asynchronous method has completed.

I tried to google and following are my observations

- Can't use await with setState calls
- setStates have a callback but can't use them as there are multiple setStates and that too in multiple methods

Suggestions?

UPDATE:
I can't actually fire a loading=true at start and loading=false at the end because in between the setStates are still working even though my code has reached to loading=false. It disables the loading but still setStates are working. They are still updating the state.

Comment: Are you using function components (with hooks) or class components?

Comment: `setState` is not really asynchronous. It has no result, there is nothing you'd need to wait for - it just dispatches a state change to react. And all these events are handled in order, so all you need to do is fire off the `loading: false` at the end of your calls. Are you doing anything that is actually asynchronous?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Yes i am using functional components with hooks.

Comment: setState is not asynchronous? I suppose it is. As you said it dispatches. Yes it does and that's what we call asynchronous right?

Comment: In function components, `setState` does not have a callback afaik. And even if the state is rendered asynchronously, we don't care, there is nothing you would need to wait for. It's not clear what you mean by "*but still setStates are working. They are still updating the state*".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't exactly tested the following code, but hopefully this will help point you in the right direction.

```js
const getContent = () => new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r("Done!"), Math.random() * 500));

function App() {
    const [ asyncContent1, setAsyncContent1 ] = useState("not ready");
    const [ asyncContent2, setAsyncContent2 ] = useState("not ready");
    const [ asyncContent3, setAsyncContent3 ] = useState("not ready");
    const [ asyncContent4, setAsyncContent4 ] = useState("not ready");

    useEffect(() => {(async () => {
        const [a1, a2, a3, a4] = await Promise.all([getContent(), getContent(), getContent(), getContent()]);
        setAsyncContent1(a1);
        setAsyncContent2(a2);
        setAsyncContent3(a3);
        setAsyncContent4(a4);
    })()}, []);

    const content = [
        asyncContent1,
        asyncContent2,
        asyncContent3,
        asyncContent4
    ];
    return (
        <div>
            {
                content.map(s => <span>{s}</span>)
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

The important part of what is happening here is the use of `useEffect`

This allows you to have a function which fires upon initial load of the page, requesting the content, and you can nest a async arrow function called immediately into `useEffect` to use the async / await syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But this won't work in my case. As i said i have multiple async methods running in 10 different methods. So can't use Promise.all and infact i have setStates. They don't actually return any promise.

Comment: maybe you're looking for `componentDidMount` if you're using React class components instead of function components.

Comment: No its on happening on didMount. Its something different. It can be triggered by the user once the component has already mounted